How to set correct EVM version, for Solidity code, on remix.ethereum.org
I am trying to deploy a smart contract from within the remix.ethereum.org environment.
Remix version;   0.58.0
Browser;  Firefox
Wallet;  Metamask
The code I am compiling and trying to deploy is the example code in the Remix environment;  Storage.sol
I compiled with version 0.8.2 and get a green checkmark for successful compile, sometimes.
Some environments will not compile.
Others compile but will not Deploy.
I have tried all possible EVM Environments.
-- cancun gives compile error "Invalid EVM version requested"
-- shanhai gives compile error "Invalid EVM version requested"
-- paris  gives compile error "Invalid EVM version requested"
-- london  gives compile error "Invalid EVM version requested"
-- berlin compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: berlin.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  istanbul compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: istanbul.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  petersburg compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: petersburg.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  constantinople compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: constantinople.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  byzantium compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: byzantium.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  spuriousDragon compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: spuriousDragon.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  tangerineWhistle compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: tangerineWhistle.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
--  homestead compiles ok but When I go to the Deploy tab I have the error;"Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version: homestead.
Otherwise any deployment will fail."
I have used the AI Help on Remix, but it seems that the AI was trained on an older version of Remix, since it gives be Buttons and Icons to click on that do not exist on the Remix page, and it offers vague, not helpful generalizations to "get the environment right".
I have taken the error text "Please make sure that the current network..." and pasted it into search engine and found dozens of hits, that I followed.
These have not helped me.
One search engine hit suggested using etherscan.io to discover the correct environment, however I don't know what info from the source code to enter there.
Any and all help is much appreciated.
xstack
====  Source Code follows

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract Storage {

    uint256 number;

    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}


Hi SYED, Here is my current environment as per your instructions;


Which evm node url are you deploying to?

@xstack check chainlink Ethereum Sepolia Faucet, you can get 0.5 daily

thank you. Working on it .....

In Remix IDE, the default selected deployment environment is Remix VM (Cancun).

To deploy to any real testnet (such as Ethereum Sepolia), you need to select Injected Provider - MetaMask from the Environment dropdown in the Deploy & run transactions tab of the side menu.

Once you select Injected Provider - MetaMask, a MetaMask pop-up will appear asking you to connect your account(s). Once connected, it will display the connected network name and the balance of the connected account.

Moreover, you can also add / remove various Remix local networks and browser-based wallet extensions in the Environment dropdown list available in the Deploy & run transactions tab of the side menu, by clicking on the Customize this list... button.



Thank you Syed ! Thank you for the great graphics. I do not get the display as you are getting. I do NOT get Sepolia, I just get Mainnet. I proceed with a transaction in Metamask and the deployment fails. Console says;  "creation of Storage pending...
creation of Storage errored: Error occurred:  [TIMEOUT] Timeout for call sendAsync from udapp.
[TIMEOUT] Timeout for call sendAsync from udapp
If the transaction failed for not having enough gas, try increasing the gas limit gently."

Thank you CT95 for reply. I do not know where to find a deployment node URL. Can you tell me where, please?

@xstack, you need to enable the Show test networks toggle as shown in the MetaMask docs.

@xstack, I've added more details in my answer. Please check.

thank you again. I have now added the network and posted a screenshot of that at the end of my original post above. Guess the next step is to figure out how to get SepoliaETH into Metamask. Thanks again.

I guess I should mention, that I still have the error message;  "Please make sure that the current network is compatible with this evm version:......"

Thank you again to all who so kindly assisted. I think that I have it working now. I banged on the remix site in every way that I could and put endless queries into search engines. What I found was an Ethereum.org howto page that seemed to say that I needed a Constructor that set Payable. When I did that, and posted to MainNet, it seemed to work. No more errors in the Console. Thanks again to all.
